# Help needed installing cygwin: may be ini file problem

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to install cygwin on my Windows 7 machine.

I get the setup by starting the install on http://www.cygwin.com/. I choose "Install from Internet" (which links to http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe), then select successively in the Wizard:

- All users + Unix text files
- local package directory = C:\Cygwin
- direct connection
- download site = mirror.cs.vt.edu (I tried a few others and ran into similar problems; if there is one in particular someone highly recommends, I will gladly try it).

I get a warning "The current ini file is from a newer version of setup.exe. If you have any trouble installing, please download a fresh version from http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe", but as far as I understand, that's exactly what I just downloaded to start this. Then I get parse errors. I have no idea where I am going wrong, or where I would go to get the correct setup.exe. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the setup.exe that's on your hard drive and try again.  Alternatively, try downloading from http://mirrors.kernel.org;  I just tried it and it works for me.  The new version should be 2.721 (as it appears on the spash screen).

Comment: @Joe Mabel:  It's happened to me a time or two.  They update the setup.exe periodically, and ... well it doesn't always work quite the way it should.

Comment: You'd think the error message would indicate that you have to delete your existing one.

Comment: Works for me. I would have thought it would have more upvotes, after being useful on a key issue of cygwin for 5 years.