# installing cygwin: setup.ini missing from http://mirrors.kernel.org

Tags: windows, cygwin, installation

I'm trying to install cygwin on a windows 2008 server. I managed to get a hold of the cygwin setup.exe version 2.721.
Since cygwin.com is down at the moment, i tried several mirrors found through the google cache of the cygwin mirrors. I ran into the same problem like this guy: [Help needed installing cygwin: may be ini file problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597229/help-needed-installing-cygwin-may-be-ini-file-problem) 
Like they suggested, I tried http://mirrors.kernel.org as mirror. It downloads some setup.bz files fine. Then I get the error "Unable to get setup.ini from http://mirrors.kernel.org/".
 Any suggestions how to install cygwin now?

Comment: Even after an year with totally 22216(views) people have faced same problem so far. Issue still there :p

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I got this error when I tried to use `http://cygwin.com/setup.exe` and not `http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe` or `http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe`. It seems the mirrors have just recently removed support for `setup.exe`. The `setup.exe` is still available to download but none of the mirrors work.

The solution is to use either the [setup-x86.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe) or the [setup-x86_64.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe).

Comment: @mitchus - Would have been great if they just 404'd the `setup.exe` since it's completely broken.

Comment: I agree -- I ended up on this thread after googling for the same problem as the OP.

Comment: I still get the problem even using setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: Worked for me using setup-x86_64.exe. Was getting same mirror issues otherwise.

Answer (score 28):

The mirror should be the full path http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin

If you get complaints about the .ini being from a newer version of setup, you'll need to find a newer setup.exe somewhere on the net that you trust.  (And cygwin guys?  Grrr for not including setup.exe in your mirrors and for not signing your exe!)

Comment: Yupp, setup works fine now with version 2.774 - and cygwin.com is online again.

Answer (score 19):

the reason is so simple:

> the setup.ini changed its's location!

just go to cygwin site, download the latest setup.exe file. it will be OK.

Comment: I confirm, just tested and none of the mirrors work anymore with the old `setup.exe` file I have. Downloading the new `setup-x86.exe` file fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

While installing, select Install through http/ftp proxy. Firewall may block the installation. Hence, proxy will help. Also try running as Administrator.

It helps..

Regards,
Frank..!!

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still getting this error even with the correct installer, make sure that you're running the setup file on your local hard drive.

My problem was that I was trying to launch the executable from a mapped network drive. Copying down and running the program locally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use another mirror? Try lug.mtu.edu or something like that. I've always had nothing but good results from there.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Hopefully their site will be back up soon. I'm wanting to re-install it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Was giving me the same `Unable to get setup from ...` error.
I used the new setup-x86_64.exe from the Cygwin.org site & had to select the option `Use Internet Explorer Proxy Settings`.

It fetched the mirror urls.
It worked that way for me.

But, if it does not fetch all the mirrors by itself, we can 
add the url `http://mirrors.kernel.org` in the Download list.

Initially, when it was not downloading the mirrors list by itself, I had tried adding the above `http://mirrors.kernel.org` url manually & it had worked that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the Same issue... Run the installer in administrator mode and set the FTP/HTTP proxy to the proxy setting configured in internet explorer. Later if the download doesn't occur try different proxies. Selecting this mirror http://mirrors.kernel.org worked for me.