# Why am I getting "No manual entry for gcc"

Tags: c++, c, windows, cygwin

When I enter:

```
man gcc
```

I get `"No manual entry for gcc"`. The same thing happens with `g++`. Why am I getting this and how can I fix it?

I have both gcc and g++ but it just doesn't seem to work when I use it on the Cygwin terminal. I'm on Windows.

Comment: In the short term, you can see the mans online: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Comment: Check whether you have some file like `/usr/share/man/man1/gcc*`.

Comment: @rodrigo It's not there.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://cygwin.com/packages/x86/gcc-core/gcc-core-4.8.2-2), the man pages are part of the gcc-core package. So check if you have this installed, and if you feel like it, try reinstalling it.

Comment: On debian this is in `gcc-doc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the help files (aka man pages) for gcc or g++ installed in cygwin. You need to re-run the cygwin setup*.exe and select it to be installed. I'm not sure which package it is though.

Comment: When I try to rerun the setup.exe and install I get `"Unable to get setup.ini from <mirror link>"`. I haven't changed anything since I last installed. Have you ever experienced this?

Comment: @templateboy: Yes, I had the same issue a week ago. I just assumed that my cygwin installation got bitrotten, since I hadn't updated it for about two years. I'll try reinstalling cygwin from scratch, but I didn't have the chance yet.

Comment: Try selecting a different mirror. I /think/ I've seen that happen when the mirror I was using was no longer available.

Comment: @rodrigo Fixed it thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18103735/1594090) answer.

Comment: @rodrigo Also, [I'm here now](http://i.gyazo.com/64ff85aa3795bb55a03bea3ea12a8bb1.png). Do you know which one I should choose?