# Error in installing cygwin

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin

I'm trying to install the cygwin but i am getting that `unable to get setup.ini from the mirrors` on the website and also I tried many mirrors incuding the http://mirrors.kernel.org. I also tried many mirrors that are suggested in the cygwin official website but none of them work.How many time I do try i get the same error and as the suggestion provided from the mirror http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin, I do getting the same error.

Any suggerstion how to install cygwin?

Comment: This question is answer [here][1], try this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496333/installing-cygwin-setup-ini-missing-from-http-mirrors-kernel-org

Comment: Yeah i already tried but getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the mirrors directly, outside of the cygwin setup?