# Unable to get setup.ini for cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am having an issue while installing cygwin. Strangely, the list of available download sites box is empty and if I manually add the mirror location from https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html, I get setup.ini missing. This posts suggest [installing cygwin: setup.ini missing from http://mirrors.kernel.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496333/installing-cygwin-setup-ini-missing-from-http-mirrors-kernel-org) that we should use setup-x86_64.exe. I am using that only, but still get the problem. Any suggestions what can I try.

Comment: Presumably you have a 64bit system.  Have you tried redownloading the setup program and trying again?

Comment: Yes but same thing happens

Comment: Can you access https://cygwin.com/mirrors.lst?