# Cygwin setup.exe hangs during install Windows 8? How should I continue?

Tags: windows, cygwin

So I have used Cygwin on and off for the past few years and I've installed it a handful of times.  However, I've never experienced the install hanging during the install process.  When this happens, the install literally freezes and doesn't budge a "bit."  I've read that this is a somewhat [common problem](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-09/msg00015.html) but like I said, I've never come across it before.

Here's a play-by-play of what I'm doing and where it hangs on me.

1. Download the Setup-x86.exe from http://cygwin.com/install.html
2. Install from Internet
3. Use "C:\cygwin" as the default root directory for all users.
4. Use "C:\Users\Austin\Downloads" as the default local package directory
5. Direct Installation
6. Use http://mirrors.kernel.org per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597229/help-needed-installing-cygwin-may-be-ini-file-problem).
7. I don't specify any additional items for the install (I thought it would best to keep it as simple as possible after running into this problem multiple times.)
8. I don't change any of the "Resolving Dependencies" (whatever those are)
9. ...and everything goes great until a certain package get's tripped up and causes the install to hang.  This is almost always a different package at a different point in the install.  In this instance, it was texinfo-5.2-1.tar.xz and the install was at 94%!  So close!!!

So what I'm looking for is how do I help the installer continue from this point?  What do I need to do to go in cygwin and give it the extra motivation it needs to finish the job.

---

**Work around to the problem above:**

So after fiddling with the install a little more, I discovered that if you close the frozen install, and re-execute the setup file, it forces the install past the point where it got snagged the previous time.  For example, after canceling the snagged install at 94% (mentioned above), I ran the setup file again and got to 95% before the install snagged again.  I repeated this setup about 5 times before successfully installing cygwin.

Like I said,  this is just a work around and may be the best/only solution.

Comment: I've got the same on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Comment: @Austin How did you re-execute the setup file, did you run while it was hanging from before, I cancelled and ran it, but it started from scratch. I've been having this problem for days now.

Comment: Hey @somethingSomething, so if I remember correctly, all I did was close the install and re-execute the .exe by double clicking on the file in my downloads folder.  I had to repeat this a number of times but each time I reran the file, the install would creep a little farther along until it finally finished.  I know it's not a very technical response but does that answer your question?

Comment: @AustinA Thanks for the reply, I understand now, I thought you meant that you somehow could restart the downloading from where you were when it froze, I see now that you mean it got further each time. Thanks, it keeps freezing on me.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the process isn't necessarily hanging -- I got all the way here in my Google search and then it started changing files. It just had no progress bar to start.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on my Win7 64 bits with the 64 bits installer. I successfully solved the problem by deleting the content of

```
c:\[cygwin_install_dir]\var\log
```

Which contained two files:

- setup.log
- setup.log.full

Restarted the installer and everything went well!

Hope this will help.

Comment: Can confirm. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 8):

https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.hang

I turned off my anti-virus software and the install proceeded through with no problems.

Comment: Turning off Windows Defender helped in my case.

Comment: AVG for me, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: This helped for me too

Answer (score 8):

I want to share my solution which worked. BTW, I tried all the solutions listed here and could not solve.

- Open Task Manager
- Kill any dash.exe or bash.exe
- Run Cygwin installation.
- Make sure to use default install path. Somehow changing
  it did not work for me.
- Get to the first stuck point
- When it is stuck at *.dash, kill dash.exe
- When it is stuck otherwise, kill bash.exe
- Then it will lead to successful setup.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same type of problem installing CYGWIN on Windows 8 by turning off my firewall. The hang up disappeared and I had no problem after that.

Answer (score 0):

Something that also worked for me, suggested from the [cygwin mailing list](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-01/msg00216.html), was doing a full rebase as follows:

1. Run `/usr/bin/rebase-trigger full` on the cygwin terminal
2. Reboot and terminate any cygwin-related processes and services
3. Run the the setup again

Answer (score 0):

Look out for the [BLODA (Big List Of Dodgy Apps)](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) in the Cygwin FAQ, and uninstall:

> BLODA - A list of applications that interfere with the normal working of Cygwin by intrusively injecting themselves in the system call chain

(Description taken from the [Cygwin acronyms list](https://www.cygwin.com/acronyms/))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work - mine was just stuck on 0/Perpetual with no progress bar. It was Windows defender, I added my cygwin folder (C:\cygwin64) into the exceptions for windows defender and progress started immediately.