# Unable to install cygwin x64 on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin

I tried a lot to download cygwin x64 on Windows 8.1 x64. As per this question, [Cygwin setup.exe hangs during install Windows 8? How should I continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917568/cygwin-setup-exe-hangs-during-install-windows-8-how-should-i-continue) I did the setup procedure, added  http://mirrors.kernel.org, deleted contents of cygwin installation directory, but still unable do download and install the program. I get error `unable to download setup.ini file`. Did anyone encountered this problem? Can someone suggest a working solution?
Per these question [installing cygwin: setup.ini missing from http://mirrors.kernel.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496333/installing-cygwin-setup-ini-missing-from-http-mirrors-kernel-org) and https://superuser.com/questions/290222/unable-to-get-setup-ini-error-during-cygwin-installation I downloaded setup-x86_64.exe but no luck.